# Is it possible to add a video on youtube but only display it on your website?

Tags: youtube

I basically want to make a video "private", but then use some code to display it public on my site. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like "unlisted" is what I want. According to [this article](http://my.umbc.edu/news/31191):

> An unlisted video is a different type of private video. "Unlisted" means that only people who know the link to the video can view it (such as friends or family to whom you send the link). An unlisted video will not appear in any of YouTube's public spaces (such as search results, your channel, or the Browse page). An unlisted video is different to a private video in these ways: you don't need a YouTube account to watch the video (you can see an unlisted video if someone sends you the video's link) there's no 25 person sharing limit

Still not sure if this is really going to help me keep prying eyes away from the video, but for now, it seems to do what I want.